# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 2: easy handle already used in multi handle

Tags: php, curl, libcurl, google-shopping-api

I am a user not a developer. The developer is not available.

This is the Google API library used in Google Shopping Products submission scripts.

The scripts worked successfully, every 20 minutes, for 2 years + the first 5 hours of yesterday.

Then the following error:

```
[18-Apr-2020 06:20:03 Europe/London] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 2: easy handle already used in multi handle (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in ../vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:162
Stack trace:
#0 ../vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(129): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Array)
#1 ../vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(89): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory))
#2 ../vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlHandler.php(43): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(ThObject(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory))
#3 ../vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handl in ../vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php on line 162
```

The only server change at around the time the scripts stopped working was a security patch applied to the physical host and a server reboot.

PHP v7.3.16

I believe the Google library in use is v2.0

I can follow instructions although will probably not understand them!

TIA

Comment: Found [this very recent WP site's thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/curl-error-2-easy-handle-already-used-in-multi-handle/) while googling, if that can help.

Comment: Thanks but I could not see any solution there

Comment: Wha t have you tried to debug the problem? Which versions of these libraries are you using? v2.0 is pretty old, so probably you need to update it?

Comment: @Nico Haase I tried updating the library to v2.1 some time ago but it broke the scripts. As I said, I am the user not the developer, so I reverted to v2.0 and all was fine, until now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just in case anyone reading this is using Laravel. We suddenly started having the same problem a few days ago, tried installing different cURL versions and setting cURL options, nothing worked. I fixed it by changing the vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php file. Look for the line that says

```
if (count($this->handles) >= $this->maxHandles) {
curl_close($resource);
} else {
...
}
```

Comment this all out, and instead of the if/else just write

```
curl_close($resource);
```

In other words no matter what the handles count is you always close the cURL connection. This worked instantly for us!

Hope it helps :)

Comment: you saved my time. Thanks.

Comment: It's generally not recommended to change files in the vendor directory, so I believe this should be considered a hotfix :)

Comment: @Mark definitely agreed yes, this should be seen as a temporary fix :) I exhausted every other possibility I could think of though, so right now this was the only way that I could get it to work.

Comment: @Matt Thanks. That worked for me. Even though it appeared the version change did (for 2 days), the issue recurred. Have yet to find out what changed on the server but , whatever it was, did not alter the cURL version.

Comment: This solution solved the problem, but changes in the vendor directory is not a good idea.

Comment: @mshoaibdev exactly and I raised this concern on the Github issue of the same package. but days gone no update. so have to take this. https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/2617

Answer (score 1):

We solved this problem together with Stripe engineers yesterday (that's not to say your problem is Stripe-related, it isn't, but the problem/solution should be the same)

(These findings are not 100% confirmed, but appear to be the pattern): It's caused when making 2+ requests via cURL and appears to happen since one of the most recent versions of cURL or at least some other software (which may have updated automatically or been done by your hosting provider)

The solution we were provided is to disable persistent connections in cURL. There are different ways of how you could do that, depending on your implementation. But for inspiration, this is how we did it with Stripe:

```
$curl = new \Stripe\HttpClient\CurlClient();
$curl->setEnablePersistentConnections(false);
\Stripe\ApiRequestor::setHttpClient($curl);
```

I imagine it would be something similar to this for your libraries. And for those looking to solve this for Stripe, here it is :)

Notice: This solution will theoretically have an impact on latency, we have however not experienced this in practice yet. But now it's mentioned :)

Comment: I was using curl 7.69.1 and downgraded to 7.19.7 which made no difference. Have changed back to 7.69.1. Is there a version you know was not a problem?

Comment: Could someone kindly apply the fix to the file "CurlFactory.php", if that is the appropriate file? If so, how do I provide access to it or paste the contents on here?

Comment: @AspiEd We are unfortunately not aware which version may be useful, and it's still a guess that cURL is the culprit. It could be another software component. But according to all reports it appears to have been some sort of update. But this was the guess from our's and Stripe's team. We disabled persistent connections in cURL to resolve the issue.

Comment: I have reverted to curl 7.69.1 and all is well again. For now, I have removed curl + libcurl from yum so they will not update. Thanks for your help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

I have reverted to curl 7.69.1 and all is well again.
For now, I have removed curl + libcurl from yum so they will not update.
Thanks for your help and advice and apologies if my style has been incorrect.

Comment: I was on v7.69.1 for past 2 days but same issue has recurred.

Answer (score 0):

public_html/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/Proxy.php

please comment these lines from this fn

public static function wrapSync(
        callable $default,
        callable $sync
    ) {

```
    // return function (RequestInterface $request, array $options) use ($default, $sync) {
    //     return empty($options[RequestOptions::SYNCHRONOUS])
    //         ? $default($request, $options)
    //         : $sync($request, $options);
    // };
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I am not using guzzle, but I had same problem with other library

php 7.4.6

curl 7.19.7

CentOS release 6.10 (Final)

package "mercadopago/dx-php": "2.0.0"

On my dev server and other server i tested it works fine

I am not 100% but I think that is a bug on curl library that doesn't allow to reuse same curl connection for more than one request (again I am not sure about it).

I solved it with a hotfix on mercadopago/dx-php I edited ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/RestClient.php

replacing line 150

from
$connect = $this->getHttpRequest();

to 
$connect = new Http\CurlRequest();

in other words, force to use new connection for next request. on your code look where connection is reused and try to create new connection instead.

I know, it sucks because:
- is a hotfix on Third-party
- cannot reuse same connection

but it worked. Hope it can help you.